# Preserving Excel function references when replacing a sheet with another of the same name

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, import

I'm creating a tool in excel that will provide a set of standards to the end user, based on the answers they provide to a questionnaire. I have a tab that shows how they user answered the questionnaire, another the details the mapping of question to standard, and another that outputs the applicable standards.

To make this tool more user friendly, I'm trying to add functionality that would allow for a user to choose an excel document from file explorer, pull the sheet within that workbook with the questionnaire answers & copy it to the workbook that is the tool. The macro will import the questionnaire (named Sheet1), delete the existing sheet that is a different set of answers to the questionnaire (named Questionnaire_Answers), then rename Sheet1 to Questionnaire_Answers.

The issue is that this does not preserve the references to Questionnaire_Answers in the mapping sheet. (i.e. VLOOKUP(B158,'Questionnaire_Answers'!$A$1:$B$60,2,FALSE) becomes VLOOKUP(B158,#REF,2,FALSE) because the sheet was deleted.

Is there a way to make the references in VLOOKUP (or any function) specific to a sheet with a given name, as opposed to a specific sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a valid workaround that eliminates this problem.

Simply uploading the new sheet, copying the range of data (sheet will always have the same data range since it is an export from a different platform) to the aptly named & referenced sheet, then deleting the source of the copy works.

This is not an elegant solution by any means.

Answer (score 0):

There is NO straightforward way for that, but you can have a few workaround :

- once the worksheet is already in the workbook change worksheet name in formulas to the actual name of the new worksheet. When you rename it formulas will be updated.
- don't replace the worksheet, just copy content to existing worksheet.